# I'm having problems finding a correct iterative methode for the towers of Hanoi problem in python

Tags: python

I have been assigned to find an iterative solution for the tower of Hanoi problem in python, and I have found pseudo-code which did help a lot. The only problem is that this pseudo-code does not help for moving a disk backwards. The following code does show the correct 2 poles involved in the movement, but not always the correct direction. Does someone know how to either solve this problem, or knows a different solution? Here is the link for the site where I found the pseudo-code https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-tower-of-hanoi/. (my code starts with the following definition but I can't get it to also be in the code block)

```
def hanoi_iterative(n):

    moves = []
    number_of_moves = 2**n-1
    starting_pole = 'A'
    middle_pole = 'B'
    end_pole = 'C'
    i = 0
    if n % 2==0:
        end_pole = 'B'
        middle_pole = 'C'
    while i in range(0,number_of_moves):
        i +=1
        if i%3 == 1:
            moves.append(starting_pole + end_pole)
        if i%3 == 2:
            moves.append(starting_pole + middle_pole)
        if i%3 == 0:
            zetten.append(middle_pole + end_pole)
    return moves
```

Answer (score 1):

for me the code is working fine, you have a typo in the code of your question (last if statement zetten.append() instead of moves.append()

```
def hanoi_iterative(n):

    moves = []
    number_of_moves = 2**n-1
    starting_pole = 'A'
    middle_pole = 'B'
    end_pole = 'C'
    i = 0
    if n % 2==0:
        end_pole = 'B'
        middle_pole = 'C'
    while i in range(0,number_of_moves):
        i +=1
        if i%3 == 1:
            moves.append(starting_pole + end_pole)
        if i%3 == 2:
            moves.append(starting_pole + middle_pole)
        if i%3 == 0:
            moves.append(middle_pole + end_pole)

    return moves

print(hanoi_iterative(3))
```

What exactly is wrong, what do you want it to do? What should a move backwards be?

Comment: For instance, if n=3, the correct code is ['AC', 'AB', 'CB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BC', 'AC'], while my code gives ['AC', 'AB', 'BC', 'AC', 'AB', 'BC', 'AC']. So in my code 'BC' and 'AB' should be switched, because you move the disc from pole C to pole B instead of otherwise. My code right now does not differentiate in which direction the disc moves, in my code the disc always moves to the right. So my code is correct for the specific poles the movement takes place, just not the direction.

Comment: @Thomas that issue comes from the statements that append your list. ```moves.append(starting_pole + mid_pole)``` it will always insert the letters in that order.